# A ‘quite’ elementary function $f(x)=\frac{x^{s-1}}{s^{x}-1}$ related to Riemann-Zeta function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, number-theory, riemann-zeta

So I was studying the following function:

$f(x)=\frac{x^{s-1}}{s^{x}-1}$ where $s$ is any natural number greater than $1$ by playing with Wolfram-Alpha a bit I observed that by taking the integral of $f(x)$ from $0$ to $\infty$ or $\int_{0}^{{\infty}}\frac{x^{s-1}}{{s}^{x}-1}$ and setting $s=2n+1$

We get the following results provided by Wolfram:

$$\int_{0}^{{\infty}}\frac{x^{3-1}}{{3}^{x}-1}=2\frac{\zeta(3)}{\ln^{3}(3)}$$

$$\int_{0}^{{\infty}}\frac{x^{5-1}}{{5}^{x}-1}=24\frac{\zeta(5)}{\ln^{5}(5)}$$

$$\int_{0}^{{\infty}}\frac{x^{7-1}}{{7}^{x}-1}=720\frac{\zeta(7)}{\ln^{7}(7)}$$

.
.
.
And so on up to some odd numbers, I know that there is no elementary way of evaluating this integral but I wanted to see a hindsight of how this results came about and how is it related to the Riemann-Zeta function!

Comment: See the subsection [Representations-Mellin Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function#Mellin-type_integrals) in Wikipedia's Riemann zeta function page. There you'll see the relation to the Gamma function (which are the various factorials you're seeing, 2,24,720) the log terms are conversions because you're looking at $s^x$ rather than $e^x$

Comment: This is so interesting, I noticed this but couldn’t care less about it. I was more obsessed with its derivation rather than finding a broad perspective thank you for your comment! I hope others provide their findings too

Comment: @peek-a-boo can this be a near closed-form for the Zeta function at odd positive numbers?

Comment: For any $s\in (1,\infty)$ (not just odd integers $> 1$), we have by making the linear change of variables $x=\ln(s)\cdot t$, that $\int_0^{\infty}\frac{x^{s-1}}{s^x-1}\,dx=\frac{1}{(\ln s)^s}\int_0^{\infty}\frac{t^{s-1}}{e^t-1}\,dt=\frac{1}{(\ln s)^s}\Gamma(s)\zeta(s)$. These are proper equal signs, so it is what it is. Whether you regard this as a closed form for values of $\zeta$ or not is entirely up to you.

Comment: This is the same exact thing as bose integral for the zeta function at $s$ closely related to the gamma function $s\in (1,\infty)$

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With variable change ${n^x=e^t}$

\begin{align}
I(n)=\int_{0}^{{\infty}}\frac{x^{n-1}}{{n}^{x}-1}dx= &\>\frac1{\ln^{n}n}
\int_{0}^{{\infty}}\frac{t^{n-1}}{e^{t}-1}dt\\
= &\>\frac1{\ln^{n}n}
\sum_{k=1}^\infty\int_{0}^{{\infty}}t^{n-1} e^{-kt}dt\\
= &\>\frac{(n-1)!}{{\ln^{n}n}}
\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k^{n}}\\
= &\>\frac{(n-1)!}{\ln^{n}n} \zeta(n)
\end{align}

which produces

$$I(3)=\int_{0}^{{\infty}}\frac{x^{3-1}}{{3}^{x}-1}dx=2\frac{\zeta(3)}{\ln^{3}3}$$

$$I(5)=\int_{0}^{{\infty}}\frac{x^{5-1}}{{5}^{x}-1}dx=24\frac{\zeta(5)}{\ln^{5}5}$$

$$I(7)=\int_{0}^{{\infty}}\frac{x^{7-1}}{{7}^{x}-1}dx=720\frac{\zeta(7)}{\ln^{7}7}$$

Comment: It’s impressive you made this evaluation to a standard form, I think you made a mistake correct if am wrong but $\frac{1}{\ln^{n}{n}}$ should it be $\frac{1}{\ln^{n-1}{n}}$ ?

Comment: @AshtineV - there is also a factor $\frac1{\ln n}$ resulting from $dt$

Comment: Hmm..I see I made the same evaluation and spot this which you can easily resolve by multiplying both sides by $\frac{1}{\ln{n}}$ thank you for your solution