# Revised: Proof verification for the function $f(x)=\frac{x^{s-1}}{s^{x}-1}$ in terms of the incomplete gamma-function and the polylogarithm function

Tags: calculus, integration, solution-verification, proof-writing

Regarding my previous post:

[A ‘quite’ elementary function $f(x)=\frac{x^{s-1}}{s^{x}-1}$ related to Riemann-Zeta function](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4415357/758643)

About the relation of the function $f(x)$ in terms of the Zeta-Function, I now give a proof of this relation via the incomplete gamma function

Again let’s supposed the integral: $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{s-1}}{s^{x}-1}dx$$=
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{s-1}{n}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{(x-1)^{n}}{s^{x}-1}dx$$ now substitute $e^{t}=s^{x}$ then simplify: $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{s-1}{n}\frac{1}{\ln^{n+1}{(s)}}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{(t-\ln(s))^{n}}{e^{t}-1}dt=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{s-1}{n}\frac{1}{\ln^{n+1}{(s)}}[\int_{0}^{\infty}(t-\ln(s))^{n}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(e^{-kt})dt]=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{s-1}{n}\frac{1}{\ln^{n+1}{(s)}}[\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}(t-\ln(s))^{n}e^{-tk}dt]$$

Isolate the last part inside the square-brackets:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}(t-\ln(s))^{n}e^{-tk}dt$$ substitute $q=(t-\ln(s))\rightarrow dq=dt$ set $w=\ln(s)$ then $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\int_{-w}^{\infty}(q)^{n}e^{-k(q+w)}dq=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{e^{-kw}}\int_{-w}^{\infty}(q)^{n}{e^{-kq}}dq$$ make another substitution with $r=kq\rightarrow \frac{1}{k}dr=dq$ and thus: $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{{e^{-kw}}}{k^{n+1}}\int_{-kw}^{\infty}{r^{n}}{e^{-r}}dr$$ which is just the incomplete gamma function and the polylogarithm function: $$Li_{(n+1)}{(\frac{1}{e})}s\Gamma{((n+1),(-k\ln{(s)})}$$

Put it all together we get: $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{s-1}{n}\frac{Li_{(n+1)}{(\frac{1}{e})}s\Gamma{((n+1),(-k\ln{(s)}})}{\ln^{n+1}(s)}$$=$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{s-1}}{s^{x}-1}dx$$